# Regarding poisson integral

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{T}, \mathbb{D}$ be the unit circle and unit disc respectively in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. For $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$, the Poisson Integral map $P:L^\infty(\mathbb{T})\longrightarrow L^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ is defined as 
$$P(f)(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2cos(\theta-t)}}f(e^{it})dt\;\;\;\;\;(re^{i\theta})\in \mathbb{D}$$

I wanted to know that for $f,g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ is $P(fg)=P(f)P(g)$?

Comment: That cannot be true. The Poisson integral gives a harmonic function in the unit disk, and the product of two harmonic function is *not* harmonic in general.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: $u(x+iy) = x$ is harmonic, but $v(x+iy) = x^2$ is not.

Comment: Can you tell about the case if $f,g$ are also holomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f \in H^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$, so $f = \sum_{n \ge 0}{a_ne^{in\theta}}$; then $P(f)(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0}{a_nz^n}$ is in $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D)}$ (bounded holomorphic) and same with $g$. But doing $fg$ we obviously do not get generally $\sum{a_nb_n}e^{in\theta}$, so the result is not true.

This being said if we use the convolution operator (sometimes called Hadamard convolution) and consider $(f*g)(e^{i\theta})=\sum{a_nb_n}e^{in\theta}$, then indeed we get $P(f*g)=P(f)*P(g)$ on the unit disk extension too, whether holomorphic, when one of $f,g$ are in $H^{\infty}$, or just harmonic in general.